# In Postgres, does an index carry through to views?

Tags: database, postgresql

Does an index on a Postgres table speed searches of views that reference it?

For example, suppose I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(my_column INT);  -- Then insert lots of rows into the table.
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT my_column FROM my_table;
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table(my_column);
SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE my_column = 1;
```

Does the SELECT statement on line 4 benefit from the index on line 3?

Comment: You could ask PostgreSQL to explain the query, then it would tell you.

Comment: If they are not materialized, I would say yes. Non-materialized views work as syntactic sugar for queries, so indexes will work the same way as if you typed the view definition instead. Nevertheless, I would look at the execution plan. Also, consider the optimization barriers changed in in PostgreSQL 12 and the optimizer can see much better through subqueries.

Comment: Note that the EXPLAIN command might give false negatives, because even if you create an index, [Postgres might wisely choose not to use it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes#why-is-my-query-not-using-an-index).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that will certainly work. The query rewriter replaces the view with its definition, and the optimizer processes the result.

`EXPLAIN` the query and convince yourself.